# How do i alias a composite value of 2 fields inside the values_list method of object_manager?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a really simple form that allows the user to select an active user from a selection list and submitting that choice to the backend. Here is my code:

```
class PeerReviewColleagueSelectionForm(forms.Form):
    ACTIVE_COLLEAGUES = CustomUser.objects.filter(is_active=True)\
        .values_list('id', full_name=F(('first_name') + ' ' + F('last_name')))\
        .order_by('full_name').annotate(Count='id')
    colleague = forms.ChoiceField(label='selecteer collega', tuple=ACTIVE_COLLEAGUES)
```

I am trying to get a list of `tuples` that can be used by the ChoiceField widget to display all the available active colleagues to choose from.

I'm trying to create an alias called `full_name` from the first_name and last_name fields of CustomUser.  Then I want to order the results by that alias and i use annotate(count) to group by id (since i know each id is unique and i want tuples consisting of `(id, full_name,)`

However when i try this it throws: `TypeError: values_list() got an unexpected keyword argument 'full_name'`

How can i make a tuple based on the id and an alias called full_name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly [`values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) doesn't accept expression keywords arguments. So you should annotate new field first:

```
CustomUser.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    .annotate(full_name=Concat('first_name', Value(' '), 'last_name') 
    .values_list('id', "full_name")
    .order_by('full_name')
```

Note that you can use [`Concat`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#concat) database function to perform string concationation.

Comment: i'm sorry i've accepted the answer too prematurely. It seems your solution is creating a Tuple list of which the tuples now consist of 3 values instead of 2. The order in such a tuple is: (id, fullName, id). ChoiceField needs the a tuple list where the tuples have 2 elements namely (id, fullName)

Comment: @FAM_Maurice I suppose this is because of `count` annotation, so third field is actually a count. Just remove it and see if it works.